# I want to open a Link in my google document (no spreadsheet) directely by menu

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

```
I want to open a Link in my google document (no spreadsheet)
directely by menu or by function !!

How to arrive with my script ?   it's simple but no one seems to understand

  function onOpen() {
      // Add a menu with some items, some separators, and a sub-menu.
          DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('OAR')

          .addItem('MAJ  Date + OAR', 'test')
          .addItem('MAJ  Date  Auto', 'testdate')
         ***.addItem('Accès Direct URL', 'href=/d/1udvLSpaZNgalg6NId JMJvkkw3i9oCaEKa-    `A_CAC79CYkvsZKD545dyZN/edit?')***
```

//(By click on Menu 'Accès Direct URL' on screen it's open an other document (hyperlink) in a new window ... it's simple but no one seems to understand`

```
           .addToUi();
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is simply not possible...

What you can do is let the menu open a popup in which you show a link that can be clicked and will redirect to a new browser tab/window.

such a code is pretty simple and goes as follows :

```
function showURL(){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(50).setWidth(200);
  app.setTitle("Show URL");
  var link = app.createAnchor('open ', 'https://sites.google.com/site/appsscriptexperiments/');
  app.add(link);  
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  ui.showModalDialog(app, 'some title')
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Serge but I have an error message when i execute item menu      "Détails du message
Fonction de script introuvable : showURL"  I don't understand  (href) in  Function showURL(href) . Can you enlighten me on the subject ?

Comment: You can remove it... it was used  as a parameter in another function and I forgot to remove it.  About your error, you probably forgot to save the script.

Comment: please start a new thread for you library integration issue., your edit has been rejected.

Comment: problem solved in my Library ... I have forget it a syntax error ..Thanks serge